# Is there a way to compile a .cs file with mono in batch?

Tags: c#, batch-file, mono

I am using Mono for mono to compile a simple command line based application, and I think compiling could be easier, so I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this in batch, I also tried some stuff myself, but it didn't work
Some batch code I tried:

```
@echo off

echo Mono version 4.2.3
echo Prepending '%~dp0' to PATH PATH=%~dp0;%PATH%

mcs Program.cs -r:NCalc -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "didn't work", add the errors you get

Comment: Cmd couldn't find mono